# onStatusChanged(String,int,Bundle) in LocationListener has been deprecated

Tags: java, android, android-location

I have this output when I build my project:

```
onStatusChanged(String,int,Bundle) in LocationListener has been deprecated
```

I've found that I have to replace it with `public class LocationProvider`. Does anyone know how I can fix it? Any idea?

Comment: _"This callback will never be invoked and providers can be considers as always in the LocationProvider#AVAILABLE state."_

Comment: Yes, but in API level 29 this status is no longer supported.

Comment: That sounds like a warning, not an error.

Comment: correct. it is a warning. but better to find a solution early because in future api verions, deprecated methods may be removed permanently.

Answer (score 0):

All methods of `interface LocationListener` must be overridden, but the warning can be ignored:

```
/**
 * Notice: This callback will never be invoked and providers can be
 * considered as always in the {@link LocationProvider#AVAILABLE} state.
 */
@Override @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
```